# Swift & Firebase: Detect revoked token

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wonder how the client (iOS) is informed on the revoked token as it is said in this guide by Google:

How can I detect (on the client device) that the token was revoked and act accordingly (either re-authenticate or sign out)?

> **Respond to token revocation on the client**
>
> If the token is revoked via the Admin SDK, the client is informed of the revocation and the user is expected to reauthenticate or is signed out:

EXAMPLE BY GOOGLE:

```
function onIdTokenRevocation() {
  // For an email/password user. Prompt the user for the password again.
    let password = prompt('Please provide your password for reauthentication');
    let credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
    firebase.auth().currentUser.email, password);
    firebase.auth().currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential)
    .then(result => {
      // User successfully reauthenticated. New ID tokens should be valid.
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // An error occurred.
    });
}
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: That is **not** Swift. Have you tried using the `catch` block?...

Comment: I know that this is not Swift. However I want to know how I can detect that the token was revoked on an iOS device (using swift)

Answer (score 1):

When a token is invalidated, all iOS client side user APIs will throw an error `FIRAuthErrorCodeUserTokenExpired` when called. You can catch that and then reauthenticate the user.

If you sending the token to your server, you can detect it as follows:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation_in_the_sdk

You can also setup your own listener to detect invalidation as soon as it happens. An example using real time database is shown: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation